# Python Ideas for fixing std I/O redirection issue in script to add GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, inputstream, stdin, outputstream

I am using a small python module I found on github to redact data from pdfs:
https://github.com/JoshData/pdf-redactor

It works very well, the only issue is that it most be invoked via command line for input / output redirection purposes, for example this is how you would call it on a file:

```
python example.py < in.pdf > in-redacted.pdf
```

I am looking for ways to change it so that the input / output files are simply strings/path variables inside the script itself, that way it will be easy to wrap a GUI around it, as right now with the redirection I'm not sure how to get the GUI to feed in the parameters.

I'm confused as when I run `print(sys.argv)` it only shows the input file, meaning the redirection removes the arguments as positional parameters.

When I look at the python library I'm using it is very much hard coded to redirect stdin / out, so I think it would be the more difficult option to try and re-write this:

```
    # This is the function that performs redaction.

    if sys.version_info < (3,):
        if options.input_stream is None:
            options.input_stream = sys.stdin # input stream containing the PDF to redact
        if options.output_stream is None:
            options.output_stream = sys.stdout # output stream to write the new, redacted PDF to
    else:
        if options.input_stream is None:
            options.input_stream = sys.stdin.buffer # input byte stream containing the PDF to redact
        if options.output_stream is None:
            options.output_stream = sys.stdout.buffer # output byte stream to write the new, redacted PDF to

    from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter
    # Read the PDF.
    document = PdfReader(options.input_stream)

    # Modify its Document Information Dictionary metadata.
    update_metadata(document, options)

    # Modify its XMP metadata.
    update_xmp_metadata(document, options)

    if options.content_filters:
        # Build up the complete text stream of the PDF content.
        text_layer = build_text_layer(document, options)

        # Apply filters to the text stream.
        update_text_layer(options, *text_layer)

        # Replace page content streams with updated tokens.
        apply_updated_text(document, *text_layer)

    # Update annotations.
    update_annotations(document, options)

    # Write the PDF back out.
    writer = PdfWriter()
    writer.trailer = document
    writer.write(options.output_stream)
```

So any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Sure, do as they do in this [example.py](https://github.com/JoshData/pdf-redactor/blob/master/example.py).  In addition, set options.input_stream and options.output_stream.  Instead of using `sys.stdin.buffer` and `sys.stdout.buffer`, open your file of choice like `open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')` for input and `open(sys.argv[2], 'wb')` for output.  Call your script like `python scriptname.py inputfile.pdf outputfile.pdf`.

Comment: That did it, wow that worked no problem with only two lines of code. Thanks!